# Jquery:TypeError: $(...)._TMS is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I download html Template. In master page I put HTML code. All query library was included. After build mvc project I don't see scroll images. But in usual html it's perfect work. I think it's because on master page I use tag:   $(document).ready(function () {. So. The Html code on master page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/Content/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/Content/grid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/Content/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/Content/slider.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Passion+One:400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/tms-0.4.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.slider')._TMS({
            show: 0,
            pauseOnHover: false,
            prevBu: false,
            nextBu: false,
            playBu: false,
            duration: 1000,
            preset: 'fade',
            pagination: true, //'.pagination',true,'<ul></ul>'
            pagNums: false,
            slideshow: 8000,
            numStatus: false,
            banners: 'fade', // fromLeft, fromRight, fromTop, fromBottom
            waitBannerAnimation: false,
            progressBar: false
        });
    })
     </script>
    </head>
```

The script tms-0.4.1.js starts with this code:

```
/* jQuery based image slider
/* TMSlider 0.4.1 */
;(function($){
$.fn.TMSlider=$.fn.TMS=$.fn._TMS=function(o){
    return this.each(function(){
        var th=$(this),
```

In browser I see error:

```
TypeError: $(...)._TMS is not a function
progressBar: false
```

In fact usual HTML perfect work with out error. Can you help me fix it?
[image]

Comment: Is file `tms-0.4.1.js` loaded sucessfully?

Comment: May be your tms.js not loaded and so unable to fine method.... try this <script src="Scripts/whateverMaybeNameOfUrTMSJS.js">

Comment: The file tms-0.4.1.js load successfully, because in browser I see, when load page, browser go to tms-0.4.1.js

Comment: Is `jquery.js` included?

Comment: yes! in project included:     <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>

Comment: You load `jquery-1.7.min.js` and `jquery-1.11.0.min.js`? Remove the last one.

Comment: I removed, and it's not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jquery above this:

```
<script src="/Scripts/tms-0.4.1.js"></script>
```

Place:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Unless you already have and you didnt show us in your code.

REVISION:

I also don't see a closing semi colon at the end of your document.ready function.

Comment: did you put a semicolon at the end of your document.ready()? Should be something like   $(document).ready(function () { $('.slider')._TMS({...Code}); });